# file not found or syntax incorrect when using Main.class.getResource("notification.wav").getFile()

Tags: java, path, getresource, audioinputstream

I am trying to play a .wav file but having trouble doing so with a relative path function.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        playSound();
    }

    public static void playSound() {
        try {
            File file = new File(Main.class.getResource("notification.wav").getFile());
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            clip.start();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error playing sound.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If I run the code above in IntelliJ, I receive the error:
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Dominik\Documents\IntelliJ%20Projects\nbbot\out\production\nbbot\com\company\notification.wav (The system cannot find the path specified)`

If I run my built .jar application, I receive the error:
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\Dominik\Documents\IntelliJ%20Projects\nbbot\nbbot_jar\nbbot.jar!\com\company\notification.wav (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect) in Java?`

The .wav file an the Main class, where I run the code snipped are in the same folder:
nbbot > src > com > company > Main.java; notification.wav

It's strange, because the paths are correct and there should be no problem to just read the file.
I also tried `Main.class.getClass().getResource("notification.wav").getFile();` and `.getPath()` but no luck either. If I just use `new File("notification.wav")` and put the .wav the project folder `nbbot` the audio plays as intendet, but only in the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plan is broken. **resources aren't usually files**. Calling `.getFile()` on a resource is usually going to get you broken code. For example, when pack up your app into a jar, boom, breaks. a `java.io.File` object can only represent an actual file.

Just about every API also lets you pass a URL or an InputStream instead of a File, use those - those are abstractions that apply to all resources.

`getAudioInputStream` is just such a method, fortunately. It has overrides for em. Write this:

```
try (AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
  Main.class.getResource("notification.wav"))) {

  Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
  clip.open(audioInputStream);
  clip.start();
}
```

This will probably fix this problem and will definitely mean that your code will continue to work once your files are packed up into a jar.

NB: InputStreams are resources that **must** be closed, hence, you need to use try-with-resources, or your app will eventually hard-crash due to running out of OS handles after playing enough audio.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware the method also accepts the URL and not a file object.